# Why are these divs wrapping and exceeding margins?

Tags: html, css, layout

There is a page that works fine and most of [the page that isn't](http://moonwards.com/about.html) is copied directly from it. It is a responsive grid layout with 12 columns. The page has one row with two divs inside it, each with a width of 50%, yet the 2nd div wraps underneath the first, and the first takes up the whole width plus goes off the right edge. It validates. What am I not seeing?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="rowR">
    <div class="darkYellow col-6 col-m-6">
        <p>
        Moonwards exists...
        </p>
        <p>
        An appreciation... 
        </p>
        <p>
        The Virtual Moon Colony...
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-m-6 black30">
        <p>
        email: info@moonwards.com
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[class*="col-"] {
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    }
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 850px) {
    .col-4r6 {width: 50%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .col-m-4r6 {width: 33.33%; margin-left: 16.66%;}
}
.rowR div, .rowR h1, .rowR h2, .rowR h3 {
    float: right;
}
.rowL:after, .rowR:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
#container {
    margin-top: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: `.col-6` is only 50% of the screen if it's at least 850px wide. That's what `@media only screen and (min-width: 850px)` is doing. When I put your code in a fiddle it works properly: 50% when over 850px and 100% when it's smaller than that. (I'm not seeing it go off the edge either)

Comment: @BSMP actually there are other statements covering under 850px. I just didn't put them in for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Your question needs to include enough code to reproduce the error.

Comment: Alright, i'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have set `.col-4r6` to have `margin-left: 16.66%` while also having the width of the `.darkYellow` to be `94%`.

`box-sizing` does not include the value set for the margin. It only calculates the size of the width, height, padding and border and therefore is extending outside of the container.

If you change `.darkYellow` to the following it should work fine.

```
.darkYellow {
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 0, 0.7);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 83.33%;
}
```

Comment: Hm, i see. But that change would create problems elsewhere. I think instead i'll nest a new div inside the columns with class darkYellow. Thanks :)